# move documents within same library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have shaepoint opi, my strucrure of documents in folders needs to be changed.
Right now I have one big folder (A) with few smaller folders (B,C,D) which contain documents with different acceses. 
I need to move all documents (with accesses) from B,C,D to the big folder A.

I get multiple errers, that I can't copy files within the same branch.

I tried to move them to a different folder and then to the folder A - no result, same error.

Can you please help woman in need :)?

Comment: Can you please clarify this question. Structure it up a bit and show some of the error messages. This will hopefully help you retrieve attention to your question :)